# date-es-ES.js doesn't include "tt"?

Tags: javascript, date, datejs

In this question, I'm referring to the well known library `date.js`:
https://code.google.com/p/datejs

With `date.js`, I can do this:

```
  alert((new Date()).toString("h:mm tt"));

  Output: 1:35 PM
```

with `date-es-ES.js`, however, with the same code, I get this:

```
  Output: 1:35
```

So... isn't tt supported in date-es-ES.js?

Comment: I think im going for moment.js, the last time date.js was updated was in 2008, so.... whatever the bugs it has, they will remain there, lol.

Answer (score 0):

Strongly suggest using my (actively maintained and vastly updated) fork of DateJS here: https://github.com/abritinthebay/datejs

The original maintainer of DateJS abandoned it - I've taken over and this shouldn't happen in the new version (if it does - PLEASE file an issue on Github, I'll fix it asap).